# Small sample difference

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, group-differences

I have 40 respondents, they answered on their preferred webpage after seeing page A and page B. Results say that 22 respondents preferred A and 18 preferred B:

```
Prefer A = 22
Prefer B = 18
n = 40
```

How can I test if there are differences among the A and B given the small sample size? Can I test the differences?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly you can test for a difference of proportion (it's equivalent to testing $P(\text{prefers A}) = \frac12$). The usual test would be the [binomial test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test), or you might use a normal approximation to the binomial (in which case, with $p_0=\frac12$ I'd suggest using a continuity correction), or a [chi-squared goodness of fit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit#Pearson's_chi-squared_test) test (or indeed other tests are possible).

However, on those data you will have no hope of rejecting the null at any reasonable significance level; under the null, the standard error of the difference between the counts will be larger than the observed difference; with $n=40$ you'd need an observed difference more than three times as big for a two-tailed p-value to reach typical significance levels.